# How to interpret bound charges geometrically?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, charge, polarization, dipole

Conceptually, it makes sense to say that when there is an electric field along $E=E\hat{n}$, then given a polarization $P$, the amount that $P$ aligns with the electric field is simply the dot product $P\cdot\hat{n}$. But why does this only apply to the surface charge? Shouldn't we use the dot product to describe the extent of alignment of the dipoles within the  material as well? That's given by $-\nabla\cdot P$. But when I visualize that, I see the amount that the polarization is approaching a point $(x,y,z)$ (creating a sink). Why is this the case? And how does it describe the amount that the dipoles align with the electric field inside the material? I hope my question is not phrased in an obscure manner.

Comment: I forgot to add. The way that the bound volume charge charge is defined, the polarization has curl within the material? That is, if we integrate the bound volume charge over the entire volume.

Comment: If you have additions to your post, you can [edit] it.

Comment: Griffiths has a nice section on this that you might want to read.